# F# GPU programing vs KDB for crunching data, what is the fastest?

Tags: f#, gpu, kdb

Hi I would like to ask for anyone's experience on what is the most cost effective and efficient way of crunching huge amounts of data with either F# GPU (using a C Nivida GPU api typeprovider for example) programing vs KDB for crunching data.

I know both are quite different approaches but just want some advice from people who have worked in both before investing in one or both technologies.

For the GPU side of things I planning to work with wither a relational DB or NoSQL DB like mongodb using single tables and simple joins of 2-3 other tables.

Does anyone know of any metrics or comparisons (speed mostly) between both approaches?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want to do? 'Crunching data' could mean any number of things, and there's no way to know if what you want to do will play to the strengths of F#, GPUs, or KDB.

Comment: Basically want to process a batch of millions of rows (10-50) every 1 min or so minutes continuously, simple statistics, nothing too fancy..

Comment: @JackP. why do people vote to delete this?

Comment: You didn't ask a question.  There are no question marks in your text.  You are asking for "everyone experience" which is a survey.

Comment: I'm assuming KDB is a software database.  So maybe you want to ask instead when will a GPU based database solution be faster than a CPU based one?  That depends on your problem but in general if your problem set can fit into the GPUs memory it will be faster.

Comment: For Cost effective: F# wins; For efficiency/Speed/convenience: K + KDB wins. If budget permitted,  I see no reason to choose F# over KDB for your application - I assume it is high frequency finance data processing.

Comment: @ahala Thanks, would you recommend KDB for less normalized data than finance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have said, too much depends on your use case as to which is faster. I previously helped create a testing framework of 15 queries and some algorithmic strategies against a few different databases of stock data:

- postgreSQL
- mysql - in memory version
- mongodb - for queries it supported
- kdb
- plus a few other newer nosql and column oriented databases

kdb database was significantly faster than those mentioned above on most queries. One database was close in terms of performance but it was significantly more difficult to get it to perform the calculations I wanted.

No I can't give hard numbers because that is against the terms of some of the database vendors. But I would emphasize if your going to build a system, the skills your team have should influence the choice. Plus your ability to quickly change the system and it's programming.

Comment: Thanks, it all makes sense. So you would say its just as easy to form your complex queries in KDB as something like MongoDB?

Answer (score 1):

In my honest opinion it is far easier to form complex queries in KDB (and understand them again afterwards) than "something like MongoDB."

I'm also an F# fan.

Now, either F# or KDB+ can help you think in a GPU compatible way (array based, whole problem at once, less linear, parallelism).  Whatever choice you make, think about the process that gets you there, and whether you are locked in to one particular world view or not.

As far as modelling is concerned, context is pretty important.  It really depends on the what kinds of models you want to run, and how throughput factors in.

KDB+'s agility, concision, and speed are awesome.  Likewise, F# is great for type safety, and for research based stuff like, say, in the life sciences.

There's nothing stopping you from using both together.  Oh, and the 32 bit version of KDB+ is now free to use in a commercial or non-commercial way.

Like John, I also tried a lot of those options from BerkeleyDB and up.  In particular, columnar options other than KDB+ lacked in several ways (not just performance).  I looked at it from a kernel perspective, and even talked to some of the engineers who worked on those kernels when the sales teams gave up.  There are fundamental reasons why KDB+, beyond benchmarks, is a smart way forward.

Speed is a factor that weighs more or less depending on the application.  Other factors and how these relate to product road-maps are probably universal.